# How to handle FileNotFoundException using try and catch block in Java?

Tags: java

I have written a program in which I am reading a file through the `BufferedReader`. which file I am reading it may be in .txt format or .csv format.
I want in if file is not available with .txt extension BufferedReader read it with 
.csv extension.

I have created a String "FileName" and storing file path on it. and in path variable i have stored file location.

```
path = "C:\Users\Desktop\folder(1)\"
```

and I am trying try catch block as follow.

```
try
    {
        FileName = path+"abc.txt";
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        FileName = path+"abc.csv";
    }

BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
```

But I am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Write down for yourself what you think that each line is doing. Think about it. Don't program by coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown in the line `BufferedReader SoftwareBundle = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));`

So you need the try/catch-block arround this line:

```
try
    {
        FileName = path+"abc.txt";
        BufferedReader SoftwareBundle = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName)); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

        FileName = path+"abc.csv";
        BufferedReader SoftwareBundle = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the ideal structure for the code:

```
String filename = null;
try (BufferedReader bundle = null) {
    try {
        filename = path + "abc.txt";
        bundle = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)); 
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        filename = path + "abc.csv";
        bundle = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName)); 
    }
    // use 'bundle' here
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    // log that >>neither<< file could be opened.
}
```

Notes:

1. Don't catch `Exception`.  If you do that, you will catch all sorts of unexpected stuff, in addition to the exceptions that you are anticipating.
2. Use a "try with resource" to ensure that that the reader that was opened is *always* closed.
3. You need to get the scoping right ... unless you are prepared to duplicate the code that uses the reader.
4. Even with the "try again" logic, you still need to deal with the case where *all* of the filenames that you try fail.  AND you need to make sure that the "all fail" case doesn't attempt to use the reader.